# I cannot use HTTP/net on my dev machine

Tags: ruby

Here is the code I am running in my rails console

```
http = Net::HTTP.new("http://google.fr",80)
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new("/stupid/url/")
res = http.request(req)
```

It makes the following error :

```
SocketError: Failed to open TCP connection to http://google.fr:80
(getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)
```

I have the same kind of error in my rails app when I try to query an API. From the same computer I can browse google. Why is it not working ?

EDIT : Same error in IRB with a `require "net/http"`

Answer (score 3):

[Docs](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-c-new) says that the address should be hostname or IP address. You are adding protocol. Or you can use URI class.

Working example (returning 404):

```
http = Net::HTTP.new("google.fr",80)
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new("/stupid/url/")
res = http.request(req)
```

Or you can try:

```
http = Net::HTTP.new(URI("http://google.fr").host)
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new("/stupid/url/")
res = http.request(req)
```

Comment: It looks like your 2nd example needs some tlc. The line ending in "req =" seems fishy

Comment: I fixed up the second code example, you can't pass a `URI::HTTP`, it must be a `String`, which is what `#host` gives.